# Structure member called by pointer have a different value assigned

Tags: c, struct

I have the following piece of C code which is showing a weird result.
S_data is a struct datatype. Could someone help me to know the reason for this

```
int i;

    typedef struct
    {
    uint8_t D[19];
    uint32_t *D_ptr[19];

    } sys_data;
```

code :

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
           S_data.D[i] = 0;
           console("%d",S_data.D[i]);
          S_data.D_ptr[i] = &S_data.D[i];
       }

       for ( i = 0; i <20; i++) {
         console("Value of var[%d] = %d\n", i, *S_data.D_ptr[i] );
         console("Address of var[%d] = %u\n", i, S_data.D_ptr[i] );
       }
```

output :

```
Address of var[0] = 536872044
Value of var[1] = 0
Address of var[1] = 536872045
Value of var[2] = 0
Address of var[2] = 536872046
Value of var[3] = 0
Address of var[3] = 536872047
Value of var[4] = 0
Address of var[4] = 536872048
Value of var[5] = 0
Address of var[5] = 536872049
Value of var[6] = 0
Address of var[6] = 536872050
Value of var[7] = 0
Address of var[7] = 536872051
Value of var[8] = 0
Address of var[8] = 536872052
Value of var[9] = 0
Address of var[9] = 536872053
Value of var[10] = 0
Address of var[10] = 536872054
Value of var[11] = 0
Address of var[11] = 536872055
Value of var[12] = 0
Address of var[12] = 536872056
Value of var[13] = 0
Address of var[13] = 536872057
Value of var[14] = 0
Address of var[14] = 536872058
Value of var[15] = 0
Address of var[15] = 536872059
Value of var[16] = 0
Address of var[16] = 536872060
Value of var[17] = 1811939328
Address of var[17] = 536872061
Value of var[18] = 74186752
Address of var[18] = 536872062
Value of var[19] = 289792
Address of var[19] = 536872063
```

Here var[17] is expected to be 0, but showing a different value. but if i print the var[17] value directly without pointer, am getting the correct result.

Comment: C or C++? Choose one.

Comment: Please add your updated code and result to the question. (Don't remove the original question) Please also show the whole function where you use that struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are violating strict aliasing rules.(`S_data.D_ptr[i] = &S_data.D[i];`) So it is undefined behavior. You can't assign pointer of one type to another like this.

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t D[19];
  uint8_t *D_ptr[19];

} sys_data;
```

This solves the problem for you.

Also print `uint32_t` using (if you declared it as `uint32_t`).

```
printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", *S_data.D_ptr[i]);
```

Also print pointer like this

```
printf("%p", (void*)S_data.D_ptr[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks , that solved the problem. but if i initialize both as 32 bit int. am still getting issue.

uint32_t D[19];
uint32_t *D_ptr[19];

result : 

Value of var[0] = 536872044
Address of var[0] = 0

Comment: @AkhilJoy Looks as if you switched pointer and content in the prints.

Comment: This is the printf code
 console("Value of var[%d] = %u\n", i, *S_data.D_ptr[i] );
console("Address of var[%d] = %u\n", i, S_data.D_ptr[i] );

 but only the var[0] is getting different value for unsigned 32bit.

Value of var[0] = 536872044
Address of var[0] = 0
Value of var[1] = 0
Address of var[1] = 536872048
Value of var[2] = 0
Address of var[2] = 536872052
Value of var[3] = 0
Address of var[3] = 536872056
Value of var[4] = 0
Address of var[4] = 536872060
Value of var[5] = 0
Address of var[5] = 536872064
etc etc

where did i go wrong ?

Comment: @Gerhardh no i didnt.. Rest of the value's & address are correct except var[0].

Comment: @AkhilJoy Maybe you have some more illegal accesses to out of bounds elements for other variables located just before that struct. You show way too little code for any conclusions.

Comment: @AkhilJoy.; Sorry for late reply but with this code we can only guess...the major problem is the posted code is pointed out. Now you should post more code but again that will be a lot. Why don't you try to use a debugger? Then come back with what debugger says.

Answer (score 0):

The part about *UB* was already explained in coderedoc's answer.

I want to add a few more details:

On some machines you will get an exception when you try to read a `uint32` from an address that is not properly aligned. Odd addresses are good candidates for a bus error, a data fetch error or similar.
This is a consequence of violating strict aliasing rule.

If you access `D_Ptr[16]` which points to `D16`, you will access the memory from `D[16]` to `D[19]` which lies partially outside of `sys_data` as `var[19]` is out of bounds. Same for the other incorrect values.
You may read the location where your counter is stored, or something else that you don't show us.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other answers have said, you are accessing your arrays as if they are able to contain 20 elements, yet they are only 19 elements in length. D[19] declares an array of 19 elements, which should be accessed using D[0] through D[18], yet you are both writing and reading using 'i' which iterates from 0 through to 19, which will be both writing and reading past the ends of your arrays, causing further undefined behaviour.